# Is injunctive relief/money compensation guaranteed when a non-breaching party sues the breacher for violating any non-disclosure agreement?

Tags: united-states, breach-of-contract, non-disclosure, litigation, injunctions

If a Non-disclosure agreement is silent on whether injunctive relief or money compensation is agreed as a result of breach of agreement, are injunctive relief and money compensation still applicable remedies neither party waived the right to receive?

Do the parties have to sign a contract mentioning injunctive relief for the non-breaching party to obtain injunctive relief, or is money compensation and injunctive relief always obtained as long as a non-disclosing agreement signed?

Answer (score 1):

> Are those getting injunctive relief guaranteed compensation for
> violating a non-disclosure agreement (NDA)?

No, unless the NDA has a legally valid liquidated damages agreement, and even then only in the event of a final, and not merely a preliminary injuncction.

> Do the parties have to sign a contract mentioning injunctive relief
> for the non-breaching party to obtain injunctive relief, or is money
> compensation and injunctive relief always obtained as long as a
> non-disclosing agreement signed?

While it is better practice for an NDA to mention injunctive relief, it isn't absolutely necessary for the non-breaching party to obtain injunctive relief.

Money compensation is not necessarily available even if injunctive relief is available.